# Bash JSON Get Length of Array

Tags: arrays, json

AWS CLI returns an empty array on filter. I want to be able to count the number of elements in that array:

```
{ "Reservations": [] }
```

vs

```
{ "Reservations": [ { "OwnerId": "124531353552" ...... } ] }
```

So if there are no results I should get back 0 (the first example).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) module to parse the JSON response
Install it via `apt-get` on ubuntu or `brew` on mac

It'll works something like this

```
╰─$echo '{ "Reservations": [] }' | jq '.Reservations | length'
0

╰─$ echo '{ "Reservations": [ { "OwnerId": "124531353552"}, { "OwnerId2": "123456789" }] }' | jq '.Reservations | length'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:
On mac, install jq first via brew.
`brew install jq`. Run your query as you did before by adding the pipe jq command.
Eg:
`aws batch list-jobs --job-queue MY-QUEUE-NAME --job-status RUNNABLE | jq '.jobSummaryList | length'`

**Explanation**
`aws batch list-jobs --job-queue MY-QUEUE-NAME --job-status RUNNABLE` when running this command the response is in the format of

> {"jobSummaryList": []}

So adding the | jq '.jobSummaryList | length' gives me the count of object inside that list. And for you it will be 'Reservations'